# How to publish my Android app on Tencent or 360 mobile?

Tags: chinese-locale, great-firewall-of-china

I have a fully working APK of an Android application I have developed. The app only have ads and some basic functions, not any Google Admob ads or any Google in-app purchases.

I wish to market this app to China, but the Google Play store is inaccessible at mainland China. So, how can I publish my app to a Chinese app market store like Tencent or 360 mobile? I can't read or write a single word in Chinese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On 360's English site, there is a form http://developer.360.cn/distribution that can allow developers to submit their apps.

Same for Tencent's English official site. http://open.qq.com/eng/reg

You can simply follow instructions on their website to submit your application.

Comment: That 360 link doesn't seem to work properly. There are a few fields for uploading document images but clicking on them does not work (tested on Chrome and Safari).

Comment: Flash plugin needs to be installed for the document upload buttons to work.

Comment: 360 link is dead. nothing to do with Flash. the page itself returns HTTP 500.

Comment: Tencent uses FLASH for file upload buttons?! Really?

Comment: Are these scam links or what?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out AppInChina http://appinchina.co/ I've already talked to them and thats who I'm going to be partnering with once my app is %100 done.  They are the best option to go with I feel like, to do it yourself is almost impossible especially with all the rules and regulations in china.

Comment: How can I do it myself, WITHOUT paying anybody any money?

Comment: I don't think that's possible to do given the new requirements especially for games now every game has to be approved by the Chinese government and they give you an approval code, this can only be done through 3rd party's   http://www.mondaq.com/china/x/554134/Gaming/SAPPRFTs+New+Administration+Regime+Over+Mobile+Games+Whatve+Happened+Since+July

Comment: @izzyMachado is it only for games or also for apps?

Comment: @batmaci it is for all apps you can find out more here, https://www.appinchina.co

Comment: have you gone through this process with appchina or without? do you have any app currently in any Chinese app store? if yes, does it worth to take these steps and effort.

Comment: I have not gone through it yet , I’m still working on finishing my app and then I will be going through it with appinchina, it will be my first app on the Chinese Android app stores. I don’t think it’s possible to do it by yourself unless you have Chinese citizenship due to new laws. I think it’s worth it though if you want to reach a big market.

Comment: @isJulian00 Did you finally try the AppInChina service? Any feedbacks or advises to share with us? Thanks.

Comment: @isJulian00 do you have any updates on this? Also is it possible just to provide a url with the APK? Thanks

Comment: any info about AppInChina pricing? I thinks, It is only for companies/corporations and not for indies.